# Get gateway's IP address

Tags: c++, networking, ip, gateway

Let I've an URL, for instance `http://www.google.com/`. I want to know all of gateway's IP addresses for package's path. Is it possible to do? If yes, please give me a pointing.

Comment: Have you tried: `man tracert`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are outside of a local network (for example you are outside of google local network) then there is no such a thing like *gateway IP* of an IP. If you mean a *default gateway*, then read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Default_gateway) for more info.

As an outside host which needs to connect to *google.com* you just can convert that domain to an corresponding IP address. To do this, you can use [`gethostbyname`](http://www.google.com/search?q=c%2b%2b%20domain%20to%20IP%20gethostbyname&sourceid=groowe&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).